# how to use created python virtual environment in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using notebook in VScode and I am working with `tensorflow==1.15.5` but in my system version is `2.3.2`.

So I created virtual environment with **python 3.7** and on system activated python is **3.8** and installed version `1.15.5`. Now I want to activate this virtual env in notebook too.

I tried selecting the interpreter (Ctrl + Shift + P) and selected the created environment. But this is not working.

I tried

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

this is still showing **2.3.2**

and even

```
!python --version
```

is showing **3.8.0**

even i tried [this article](https://anbasile.github.io/posts/2017-06-25-jupyter-venv/) but this is not working too. I am not using conda, any help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your virtual environment is **activated** and **selected as python interpreter** in VS Code, and don't forget to select it for Jupyter.

> [Select and activate an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

I create a virtual environment called `venv` and install tensorflow2.5.0. When i select `venv` as interpreter for .py file and .ipynb file, it will exactly show the same verison of tesorflow installed in new created `venv`:

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

In [Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks), it says

> To work with Jupyter notebooks, you must activate an Anaconda
> environment in VS Code, or another Python environment in which you've
> installed the [Jupyter package](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter/).

That's why you install `conda` and it worked, and even though you select `venv` but no jupyter package in it, it wouldn't be used when running code cells.

Comment: yes i have selected and actovated the created env, but no luck

Comment: So now your question is it's showing `venv` in the top right corner of Jupyter, when you run code, it still uses the global python environment? Run `import sys print(sys.version) print(sys.executable)` in Jupyter to check the current used python in Jupyter, Is it as the same as the one in top-right corner of Jupyter?

Comment: yes, it is using venv but still refer to global python and global packages, i installed conda, and no changes i have made, and it worked

Comment: @SunilGarg. Got the reason! Please have a look at my answer update.